# Explicit solution to IVP of PDE $\rho_t = [\rho (1-\rho)]_x$

Tags: partial-differential-equations, hyperbolic-equations, transport-equation

When trying to determine the density profile $\rho(t,x)$ of a system of particles I came across the PDE:
$$\frac{\partial \rho}{\partial t}=\frac{\partial}{\partial x}\big(\rho (1-\rho)\big), \qquad\text{for all}\qquad x \in \mathbb{R}, t>0,$$
with the initial condition
$\displaystyle \lim _{t \rightarrow 0^{+}}\rho(t,x)=\mathbb{1}_{\{x<0\}}$.

Does this equation have an explicit solution?

I tried the solution of the form $\rho(t,x)=h(x/t)$ which leads to $h(u)=\frac{u+1}{2}$ but the initial condition is not satisfied.
By $\mathbb{1}_{\{x<0\}}$, I mean the Heaviside step function (i.e., the [characteristic function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Characteristic_function) of $\Bbb R_-^*$).

Comment: What do you mean by $1_{x < 0}$? Does anything happen for $x \geq 0$? Otherwise the solution is just $\rho = 1$.

Comment: Isn't $\rho(t,x) = 1_{x<0}$ a solution for all $t$?

Comment: @AEngineer $\mathbb{1}_{x<0} =  1$ if $x<0$ and $0$ otherwise.

Comment: @Winther Yes except at $x=0$. I edited the question to make it clearer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The PDE $\rho_t + Q(\rho)_x = 0$ with the flux $Q(\rho) = -\rho (1-\rho)$ corresponds actually to the Lighthill-Whitham-Richards (LWR) [traffic flow](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Macroscopic_traffic_flow_model) model for cars propagating towards decreasing $x$, where $\rho$ denotes the car density.
The initial-value problem $\rho(x,0) = 1$ for $x< 0$ and $\rho(x,0) = 0$ for $x\geq 0$
is a Riemann problem. The situation can be interpreted as a one-way road, which is saturated for $x<0$ and empty for $x\geq 0$. Using the [method of characteristics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Method_of_characteristics), we obtain the set of lines along which $\rho$ is constant (represented below in the $x$-$t$ plane):

[image: characteristics]

The Lax entropy condition tells that the admissible solution is a shock wave, since characteristic curves intersect. According to the Rankine-Hugoniot condition, the shock propagates at the speed $s = 0$.
The solution
$$
\rho(x,t) = \left\lbrace
\begin{aligned}
&1 &&\text{if}\quad x<0 \\
&0 &&\text{if}\quad x\geq 0
\end{aligned}\right.
$$
is a static discontinuity located at $x=0$, which is coherent with intuition. Indeed, since the cars are moving towards decreasing $x$, the cars initially located in the saturated part $x<0$ cannot move forward.

The opposite situation where $\rho(x,0) = 0$ for $x\leq 0$ and $\rho(x,0) = 1$ for $x> 0$ may be interpreted as a red light located at $x=0$, which turns green at $t=0$. Cars initially located in the saturated half-line $x>0$ can move forward towards decreasing $x$. The entropy solution is a rarefaction wave (i.e., a self-similar smooth solution) of the form
$$
\rho(x,t) = \left\lbrace
\begin{aligned}
&0 &&\text{if}\quad x\leq -t \\
&\tfrac{1}{2}(1+x/t) &&\text{if}\quad {-t} \leq x\leq t \\
&1 &&\text{if}\quad x> t
\end{aligned}\right.
$$

Answer (score 1):

$$\frac{\partial \rho}{\partial t}-\frac{\partial}{\partial x}\big(\rho (1-\rho)\big)=0\qquad;\qquad \rho(0,x)=\mathbb{1}$$
As already pointed out in comments, an obvious solution is :
$$\rho(x,t)=1$$
If one cannot see that at first sight, one can solve analytically the PDE.

The Charpit-Lagrange system of ODEs is :
$$\frac{dx}{1}=\frac{dt}{-\rho (1-\rho)}=\frac{d\rho}{0}$$
A first characteristic equation is :
$$\rho=c_1$$
A second characteristic equation comes from $\frac{dx}{1}=\frac{dt}{-c_1 (1-c_1)}$ :
$$x+c_1(1-c_1)t=c_2$$
The general solution of the PDE is expressed on the form of the implicit equation :
$$\rho=F\left(x+\rho (1-\rho)t\right)$$
where $F$ is any function (to be determined according to the boundary condition).

Boundary condition :
$\rho(0,x)=1=F\left(x+1 (1-1)t\right)=F(x)$

The function $F$ is determined : $F(x)=1$ any value of $x$.

We put it into the general solution, which leads to the particular solution satisfying the boundary condition :
$\rho=F\left(x+\rho (1-\rho)t\right)=1$
$$\rho(x,t)=1$$
Of course, the general solving only to get such an obvious solution is like using a sledgehammer to kill a fly.